# How to insert JavaScript to Power BI Report Server

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I need to insert my own JavaScript to Power BI Report Server page at:

```
http://server/reports/browse/
```

I know, that it is possible at report viewer page by editing this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx
```

I need to customize this:

[image: power bi dashboard]

Comment: You can use the ASPNET ?

Comment: It works without IIS (directly with http.sys), but i see .aspx, so yes

Answer (score 0):

There is a branding package feature in Power BI Report Server. You can use it to change any background feature you want. Use this link for reference and thank me later!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The question is how insert my own JavaScript.

Comment: IMHO using branding package is the only way to apply custom color settings. Basically there is no way to insert custom scripts anywhere to change backgrounds of buttons or for that matter any other objects. This is handled through a json file. We can mention the color coding for the objects and then upload it to the server. That's the only way to change background colors and other color settings. If you are trying to achieve something else then do let us know.

Comment: Yep, I desire to add custom pop-up with data from ajax responce

Comment: this answer shows only how to customize some elements of pbi rs main page but does not solve the main problem - inserting custom js in it.